# Mean curvature flow starting from a wildly embedded 2-sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a wildly embedded 2-sphere in 3-sphere $S^3$. For simplicity, we may assume that $\Sigma$ is the [Alexander horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere).

> *Question*. Can we define the mean curvature flow (MCF) starting with $\Sigma$ and evolving towards a smoothly embedded 2-sphere (within a short time)?  If not, are there other curvature flows can capture such a phenomenon?